# Merge Two Dataframes by Taking Average without Id column

Tags: python, pandas

I have to dataframes that look like this:

```
weighted
    id                  10      20      
0   2020-04-01-10001    0.23    0.25    
1   2020-04-01-10003    0.73    0.75    
2   2020-04-01-10005    0.49    0.50    

benchmark
    id                  10      20      
0   2020-04-01-10001    0.15    0.16    
1   2020-04-01-10003    0.52    0.56    
2   2020-04-01-10005    0.31    0.33
```

The id column needs to be kept. I need a dataframe that looks like

```
combined
     id                 10      20      
0   2020-04-01-10001    0.19    0.205   
1   2020-04-01-10003    0.625   0.655   
2   2020-04-01-10005    0.4     0.415
```

So basically, I need all the numerical cells of the 10 and 20 column to be averaged, but keep the id column the same. I tried

```
combined = pd.concat([weighted, combined]).groupby('id').mean()
```

but this gives me

```
combined
                    10  20  
id                                  
2020-04-01-10001    0.23    0.25    
2020-04-01-10003    0.73    0.75    
2020-04-01-10005    0.49    0.50
```

Where the columns are not averaged and for some reason id is on a different level from 10 and 20. I'm really confused about why this is happening. Any explanation or pointers would be very helpful! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working correcly, because in `concat` is passes `benchmark` DataFrame:

```
combined = pd.concat([weighted, benchmark]).groupby('id').mean()
print (combined)
                     10     20
id                            
2020-04-01-10001  0.190  0.205
2020-04-01-10003  0.625  0.655
2020-04-01-10005  0.400  0.415
```

Your output is different, because instead `benchmark` is passed `combined`:

```
combined = pd.concat([weighted, combined]).groupby('id').mean()
print (combined)
                    10    20
id                          
2020-04-01-10001  0.23  0.25
2020-04-01-10003  0.73  0.75
2020-04-01-10005  0.49  0.50
```

Comment: You are so right, and I am very stupid for overlooking this. Thank you for this

Comment: @AlexPeniz - I think not, its happens very easy for many coders...